# Will a DVI splitter work for connecting multiple computers to one monitor

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, display, dvi

I have two computers at home and my monitors have 1x DVI.

One of those computers is a Lenovo Thinkpad in a docking station, and it does not have analog pins on its DVI output.

I found this DVI spitter for a reasonable price:
[image: DVI Splitter]

My question is: Will this work with two outputs that merge into one input. In other words one monitor to two computers?

Comment: Why don't you just buy a KVM switch?  This CANNOT be used to hook up one monitor to TWO computers.  This cable can be used to hook up two monitors to a single computer, and duplicate, the same image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @Ramhound, this adapter will not do what you want.  With KVM switches priced quite reasonably, that would be the best solution.

Comment: A dual DVI KVM costs several hundred dollars US, and that is a lot compared to what the splitter costs. It would however solve my issues with switching USB cables.

Comment: KVM switches are anything but reasonably priced, being at least $200 for a dual dvi version.

Comment: @Callum Rogers  I found a Startech one at around CAN$80. I understand there are many that are more costly and more full featured.

Comment: I went for an [IOGEAR 2-Port Dual-Link DVI Cable KVM with Audio (GCS982U)](http://www.amazon.com/IOGEAR-2-Port-Dual-Link-Cable-GCS982U/dp/B0073W6YDA/) in the end. It hasn't arrived yet.